# Why don't administrators have access to "system" permissions?

Tags: windows, security, permissions

In Windows, the highest level of privilege you can have is administrator permissions. But when you install an app like an antivirus, they have System permissions which is one level above admin, and this is what I don't understand.

Why are such permissions given to an application rather than a user? Such apps literally have access to everything, even to places that you can't see with admin permissions, and can prevent you from even stopping the process (which helps viruses defend themselves). They can even inject things in the bootloader and possibly the BIOS. Why does Windows give programs more permissions than administrators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between `SYSTEM` and administrators is not one of security, but of safety. It's primarily to prevent people from accidentally destroying important files and registry keys. (Perhaps it also guards against unsophisticated malware, but that's not the main goal here - admins can do anything if they try hard enough.)

System services run as `SYSTEM` because that account is specifically designated for use by things that aren't tied to a specific user. The `SYSTEM` account also has a special privilege - `SeTcbPrivilege`, or *Act as part of the operating system* - that allows it to create logon tokens for any user without knowing their password. Administrators don't have that privilege by default (though they can assign it to themselves) because there's no reason for them to take advantage of it - they install apps to manage such things. (They could write their own apps to take advantage of those powers, though.)

You also mentioned the ability of some programs to stop themselves from being terminated. These are called [protected processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn313124(v=vs.85).aspx) and cannot be terminated by any user-mode process, not even by things running as `SYSTEM`. The protection is enforced by the kernel to stop viruses from tampering with antivirus programs.

Comment: thx dude now i know and also what i thought is wrong, i never saw any article covering it so i decided to post here, thx again :)